# ENC_KEY_LEN error while running the Queries Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, oracle-data-integrator, databricks-sql, databricks-connect

I am facing below mentioned issue while running the queries on Azure Databricks using Oracle Data integrator , please help me resolve this issue.

***Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: [Databricks]DatabricksJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Configuration ENC_KEY_LEN is not available.:48:47, org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServerErrors$:hiveOperatingError:HiveThriftServerErrors.scala:65, com.databricks.sql.hive.thriftserver.thrift.ErrorPropagationThriftHandler:runSafely:ErrorPropagationThriftHandler.scala:124, com.databricks.sql.hive.thriftserver.thrift.ErrorPropagationThriftHandler:ExecuteStatement:ErrorPropagationThriftHandler.scala:73***

Comment: Have you verified that the Databricks cluster's encryption key length configuration is configured correctly, if not check the ENC_KEY_LEN value in the cluster configuration settings

Comment: There is no such setting, if you have any evidence to support this , please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight forward option to connect ODI with Azure Databricks SQL endpoint.

Found one workaround to connect ODI with Databricks using ODI sqlunload utility , which takes the inputs as query and generate a file as an output , that file can be loaded further into target DB.